# How to execute html code only when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I want to run this html code only when I click a button:

```
<div class="modal-bg">
    <div id="modal">
        <span>Sign In<a href="#close" id="close">&#215;</a></span>
        <form>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <a id="forgot-link" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button's html code is:

```
<span class="button" onclick="javascript:buttonClicked();">Sign In</span>
```

I want to create the buttonClicked() function in order to load the html code above (the form etc).
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the DOM completely, or just hide it?

Comment: First of all I'm new to JavaScript. Currently, when the button is clicked the function buttonClicked() has a simple alert message.Instead of this i want to "load" the modal-bg div code

Comment: Simple first hide div modal-bg and show it on button clicked event.

Comment: Please can you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <button id="showdiv">Show</button>
    <div class="modal-bg hide">
    <div id="modal">
        <span>Sign In<a href="#close" id="close">&#215;</a></span>
        <form>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <a id="forgot-link" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("ready", function(e){
    $("#showdiv").on("click", function(){
    $("div.modal-bg").removeClass("hide");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Class hide should have valid css to hide the div. in div with class modal-bg.